# Name of a comic book with protagonist by the name of York (most probably)

Tags: story-identification, comics

I am trying to identify a comic book I came across as a child in the early nineties of the twentieth century. It was most probably coming from an English speaking country, but I know it from a Polish magazine in which only a short translated fragment was reproduced. I found it really haunting but I found no other trace of it ever since. I have had no access to the comic book since then and all online searches have been futile so far.

The protagonist name was, as far as I can recall, York. The setting was somewhat Victorian, 19th century, but possibly more similar to New York than London of that time. The plot contained supernatural elements: weird alien creatures (“a stain”), mysterious temples, ancient civilization living underneath the sea with an artificial sun which must be regularly brought to the surface in order to recharge using “our” sun, telekinesis, telepathy, and the mention of a critical point on the surface of Earth with the potential to destroy it upon an application of only tiny force. It is funny how much I can still remember after reading it once thirty years ago. I found it really cool.

Has anyone ever heard about this comic book and could point me to it?

Comment: No need to correct the information in the question ; this way, other people who also misremember it will be more likely to find your post, and see the answer in the answer box below :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a mistake (failing memory) in my original question, the name of protagonist ist **Rork** and the comic is actually not so unknown. It seems to be a French book.

"Rork" by author Andreas

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rork

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andreas_(comics)